# python elasticsearch timeout error when indexing large json

Tags: python, elasticsearch

i'm getting timeout exception while i indexing huge json text.

**sample code:**

```
es.index(index="test", doc_type="test", body=jsonString)
```

So i tried to increase the timeout using

```
es.index(index="test", doc_type="test", body=jsonString, timeout=60)
```

But is this the only way to fix the problem? sometimes my JSON String will be 40 MB to 60 MB in size.

**Update:**

I tried below way to index using bulk, it failed.

```
helpers.bulk(es, jsonOutput, index="test-las", doc_type="test-las")
```

**Log:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LasioParser.py", line 46, in <module>
    helpers.bulk(es, jsonOutput, index="test-las", doc_type="test-las")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 257, in bulk
    for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 192, in streaming_bulk
    raise_on_error, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 137, in _process_bulk_chunk
    raise BulkIndexError('%i document(s) failed to index.' % len(errors), errors)
elasticsearch.helpers.BulkIndexError: (u'500 document(s) failed to index.', [{
```

Comment: try to use the bulk api http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html . If you provide more sample of your code, i could help you

Comment: @Lupanoide: can you give me some code examples for this?

Comment: I have posted some code in the answer

Comment: @Lupanoide: please find updated question, is this correct way of doing it, i got some error.. i will try your solution now..

Comment: is your jsonString a dict or you have just converted it with json.dumps()? It must be a dict

Comment: i have converted the dict to json string using `json.dumps(dict)`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using http compression?

`from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(hosts, http_compress = True)`

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/#compression